# Can I use Google drive as database for my Android app

Tags: android, database, google-drive-android-api

I'm new to Mobile development and I'm trying to create a PDF Android app (to launch it in playstore) and I have a lot of PDF files that I will use and they are stored in my Google drive so my question is can I use Google drive as my database, is it possible when there are a lot of users or there could be problems and is there other solutions.

I managed to create a simple version where it works fine but I'm the only user (I installed it directly from Android studio to my phone) but I have no idea if it will work when I launch it on playstore.

Comment: i am not expert of google drive but I have check that google drive let's create direct download link if you want to use google drive as just pdf storage then you can upload pdfs and generate direct download link from that uploaded document and then save it to any database then you can download that files with that link

Comment: Thank you for the answer but is there another solution, I want to know all my choices here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i am not expert of google drive but I have check that google drive let's create direct download link if you want to use google drive as just pdf storage then you can upload pdfs and generate direct download link from that uploaded document and then save it to any database then you can download that files with that link